# Resetting a JSF Backing bean from theme navigation menu in WPS 7.0

Tags: jsf, navigation, themes, backing-beans

I have a JSF Portlet which has user form in the view JSP. The requirement is whenever i click on the theme navigation menu, a new form needs to be displayed to the user. But the problem is whenever i click on the menu, the values are getting retained. Please suggest how to the remove/re-initialize the backing bean on click of theme navigation.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Can you provide some code that demonstrates the problem?  There is not enough information here to get a clear understanding of your issues.

Comment: @maple_shaft: Hey thanks for checking it out. My initial problem was that i had a JSF portlet deployed in WPS 7.0. When i click on the theme navigation menu, the portlet JSP is displayed with a form. Once i submit the form and if there is any exception, the values in the form fields are not getting removed. But my requirement is to display a fresh form whenever the portlet view JSP is invoked from theme navigation. I did a workaround by adding a queryString parameter to the navigation URL generation and in my doView i am checking for the parameter and if its not NULL, then display a fresh form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround by adding a queryString parameter to the navigation URL generation (since we are using custome themes) and in my doView i am checking for the parameter and if its not NULL, then display a fresh form. Hope it helps